# Is it worth it to follow code conventions of Netbeans?

Tags: php, coding-standards, conventions, netbeans

I am always not able to follow Netbeans default coding conventions like the following

[Function should be N lines only](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227747)

> Method Length is N Lines (M allowed)

[Warning: Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767894/warning-do-not-access-superglobal-post-array-directly-on-netbeans-7-4-for-ph)

```php
// Using this
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');

// Instead of this
$_POST['username'];
```

And many more.

It seems really hard to follow all of the coding conventions. So, what can I achieve if I follow it 100 %?

Comment: functions should be N lines max, depends how big N is. The _POST array however, sounds sensible advice - what filter_input does will tell you why.

Comment: @gbjbaanb in netbeans the default is 20, so everytime my function passes that limit if warns me.

Comment: If you do not have your own coding standards in place, then the answer is YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have your own coding standards in place, then either write it, or adopt one. I do not know what netbeans coding standard is, so I can not say whether it is good or bad.

[This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1333/20065) explains why a coding standard is impotant, and as Uncle Bob said :

> 6. After the first few iterations, get the team together to decide.

meaning that you should get a standard, and change it acording to the needs of your team.